# ROS Answers SE migration: Ros on cloud

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone

I am trying to run ros from the ubuntu virtual machine on my windows 10 operating system. Can we run ubuntu and ros on cloud platforms?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348409/ros-on-cloud/) by [jean01](https://answers.ros.org/users/53181/jean01/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generially speaking - yes it is possible - get Ubuntu (or other OS where ROS is supported) from your cloud provider and you should be able to install and run ROS.

---

Originally posted by [viktor.holova](https://answers.ros.org/users/51651/viktor.holova/) with karma: 201 on 2020-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jean01](https://answers.ros.org/users/53181/jean01/) on 2020-04-08**:
Thank you Victor.